# Sending FormData not working in React-Native

Tags: javascript, api, react-native

I tried to communicate with an API to send a picture from an Iphone. I send form data by using Postman (key: mainPicture, value 'the file I choosed') and it's working well.

The problem come when I try to do it in js: the API don't find the file in my request.

Here is my code:

```
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('mainPicture', {
    uri: mainPicture.uri,
    type: 'image/jpg',
    name: `${mainPicture.id}.jpg`,
  });
  // ...
  // api come from apisauce package
  api.post(API_RES_IMG, formData, { headers: { ['Content-Type']: 'multipart/form-data' } })
```

Server say: "Error: Multipart: Boundary not found"

Without the content-type the server receive:

```
{"_parts":{"0":{"0":"mainPicture","1":{"uri":"assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=DE830A54-2526-44CB-81FE-00786D152080&ext=JPG","type":"image/jpg","name":"1e23519b-2006-4676-b63c-624e8198e17b.jpg"}}}}
```

Too much struggle from a simple thing.

Comment: you might be getting some error? and more code related to it doesn't harm :)

Comment: Yep, updated the post

Comment: just remove the `Content-Type` , it will work see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35795529/fetch-api-and-multer-error-while-uploading-file

Comment: Nop, not working :'(

Comment: where are you getting the image uri from?

Comment: From photo roll. When I try, with the content-type to touch requestbin it say error 500 internal server error.

Comment: I just found, I had a transformers that was touching the request... Thanks for your help.

Comment: How did you solved this , please tell me, i am also having same @Kornflexx

Comment: @kvadityaaz I had client-side HTTP request middleware that was changing my request content on the fly. You should try to do your request outside your code base.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of issues I see here:

1) When using the fetch API, we don't need to set the Content-Type header, as fetch will take care of that, plus it will also take care of filling in the boundaries. I am assuming that this is the same with apisauce, however I might be wrong.

2) type: 'image/jpg' is not a valid mime type. It should be type: 'image/jpeg'.

Answer (score 0):

you should add the content type

'Content-Type': type === 'form' ? 'multipart/form-data' : 'application/json',